# How to extract PE-Header Info in java project?

Tags: java, portable-executable

I need to extract some fields from `Portable Executable` header and use their values in a java project. How can I combine the different plugins that exist (e.g., `PE-Explorer`, `PE-Info`) in my Java project.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: Hmmm.. doing this in java which has no pointer arithmetics, fair difficulty. It depends on what fields you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice to just create a binary reader and read the bytes yourself acording to the file format.
It's not hard and you can just extract what you need.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx